# Using data of one class in another class (Java/FileMenuHandler)

Tags: java

I have two different FileMenuHandler's for a GUI, I need a way to use the data stored in the TreeMap from FileMenuHadler in EditMenuHandler. EditMenuHandler is supposed to ask the user to enter a word and search in the TreeMap if the word exists.

I tried to create an instance of FMH in EMH but the Tree was always empty, how can I save the values of the tree once the file is opened and then use it for EditMenuHandler?

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class FileMenuHandler implements ActionListener{
    JFrame jframe;//creating a local JFrame 
    public FileMenuHandler (JFrame jf){//passing WordGUI Jframe
       jframe = jf;
    }

    private Container myContentPane;
    private TextArea myTextArea1;
    private TextArea myTextArea2;
    protected ArrayList<Word> uwl = new ArrayList<Word>(); 
    protected TreeMap<Word, String> tree; 

    private void readSource(File choosenFile){
        String choosenFileName = choosenFile.getName();
        TextFileInput inFile = new TextFileInput(choosenFileName);
        
        myContentPane = jframe.getContentPane();
        myTextArea1 = new TextArea();
        myTextArea2 = new TextArea();

        myTextArea1.setForeground(Color.blue);
        myTextArea2.setForeground(Color.blue);

        Font font = new Font("Times", Font.BOLD, 20);
        myTextArea1.setFont(font);
        myTextArea2.setFont(font);

        myTextArea1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        myTextArea2.setBackground(Color.yellow);




        String paragraph = "";
        String line = inFile.readLine();
        while(line != null){
            paragraph += line + " ";
            line = inFile.readLine();
        }

        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(paragraph);
        tree = new TreeMap<Word,String>();
        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
            
            String word = st.nextToken();
            Word w = new Word(word);
            uwl.add(w);
            tree.put(w,w.data);

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < uwl.size(); i++){
            myTextArea1.append(uwl.get(i).data + "\n");
        
            }
            
            myTextArea2.append(tree + "\n");

        
        myContentPane.add(myTextArea1);
        myContentPane.add(myTextArea2);

        jframe.setVisible(true);           
     }


    private void openFile(){
        int status;
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("./");
        status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        readSource(chooser.getSelectedFile());

    }
//instance of edit menu handler

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String menuName = event.getActionCommand();
        if (menuName.equals("Open")){
            openFile();
        }
        else if (menuName.equals("Quit")){
            System.exit(0);
        }
            
     } //actionPerformed

}
//
```

```
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EditMenuHandler implements ActionListener {
    JFrame jframe;

    public EditMenuHandler(JFrame jf) {
        jframe = jf;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String menuName = event.getActionCommand();
        if (menuName.equals("Search")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Search");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can achieve it in two different ways. 1st you can mark the treeMap static and can access it in EditMenuHandler. 2nd way is that you have to compose the FileMenuHandler in EditMenuHandler and then you can populate and use the treemap of FileMenuHandler in it. Although there are so many pattern based approaches are available to do so but for simplicity you can one of these two tricks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to do this,

1. you can declare a static filed (not recommended)
2. use RXJava or LiveData
3. use EventBus
4. use interface as a listener
   ....